# Validate string locale using java and regex

Tags: java, regex

I am having difficulties writing a regex that validates [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html) existing locales...

What I have done until now is this regex **`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,10}$`** .

But with this regex the following locales

**1**.`aa_aa_aaaa` Only the second group of letters must contain 2 or 4 letters.

**2**. `aaaaa` must contain at least one underscore.

Any help is much obliged! Thanks!

Comment: The locale list doesn't seem like something that will change often, why not make an enum or a list which contains them all and then match those against the input?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe there is a better solution than using regular expressions ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?i)[a-z]{2}_(?:[a-z]{2}){1,2}(?:_[a-z]{2})?$
```

Where `(?i)` is for case insensitive.

Comment: your's has only one problem {2,4}, this means that the second group may contain 3 letters, which is incorrect, how can it be specified "2 or 4 letters" not "2 too 4 letters"?

Comment: @aurelius: Right, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your expression a bit to add those additional constraints.

Basically you'd have this:

```
^[a-z]{2}(_([a-zA-Z]{2}){1,2})?_[A-Z]{2}$
```

This would match locales in the formats `aa_AA` or `aa_aAaa_AA`, i.e. there need to be at least two 2-letter groups and an optional 2 or 4-letter group in between (the group must consist of one 1 or 2 2-letter subgroups).

Note that I made the expression case-sensitive, i.e. the first 2-letter group needs to be lower case and the last (second or third) group needs to be upper case, as implied by the list you posted. The optional 4-letter group would allow both cases.

If you don't need the expression to be case-sensitive just at `(?i)` at the front of the expression.

However, that just checks the format of a potential Locale id. You'd still not know whether that id is actually supported. Thus you could just skip that step and look up the locale with that id from the available locales. I'm not sure there is any built-in functionality for that but you could create a map of `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` with the key being the id returned by `Locale#toString()` and then do the lookup using that map.

Comment: t doesn't match `no_NO_NY` (Norwegian (Nynorsk) Norway)

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE you're right, I'll update the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here are regexps of `toString()`-ed form for, say, `java.util.Locale`

For most cases, you'll probably be good with

- lang and country

```java
^(?i)(?<lang>[a-z]{2,8})(?:_(?<country>(?:[a-z]{2})|(?:[0-9]{3})))?$
```

- lang, script, country

```java
^(?i)(?<lang>[a-z]{2,8})(?:_(?<script>[a-z]{4})_)?(?:_(?<country>(?:[a-z]{2})|(?:[0-9]{3})))?$
```

- lang, script, country, variant

```java
^(?i)(?<lang>[a-z]{2,8})(?:_(?<script>[a-z]{4})_)?(?:_(?<country>(?:[a-z]{2})|(?:[0-9]{3})))?(?:_(?<variant>(?:(?:[0-9][0-9a-z]{3})|(?:[0-9a-z]{5,8}))(?:(?:_|-)(?:(?:[0-9][0-9a-z]{3})|(?:[0-9a-z]{5,8})))*))?$
```

*this pattern doesn't extract separate `subtags` - don't think there are use-cases to get them one-by-one.

- lang, script, country, variant, extension(s)

```
...gets too long and ugly )
```

These forms accept `_` (underscore) between parts (e.g. regex groups) which are more in compliance with the spec.

If allow pass `-` (hyphen) as well, which is allowed in, for example, `java.util.Locale` this won't, again, make pattern prettier.
To achieve that you may substitute `-` with smth like `(?:_|-)`, but generally speaking I like to underscore and embrace people use them.

Also, It is also more in line with «IETF BCP 47 which is composed of RFC 4647 "Matching of Language Tags" and RFC 5646 "Tags for Identifying Languages" to accept just `_` (underscore).

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-z]{1,8}(([_-]{1})([A-Z]{1})([a-z]{1,8}|[A-Z]{1,2}))?([-_]([A-Z]{1,4}|[0-9]{2,4}))?$
```

Hope this Regex may help